# Como ordenar a posição de uma matriz automaticamente?

Tags: php, array

Exemplo, eu tenho:

```
$matriz = array("Tomate", "Morango", "Melancia");
```

Eu teria:

```
(
    [0] => Tomate
    [1] => Morango
    [2] => Melancia
)
```

Mas se eu fizer:

```
unset($matriz[0]);
```

Terei:

```
(     
        [1] => Morango
        [2] => Melancia
)
```

Como ordenar automaticamente para que voltem do `0`

```
(     
        [0] => Morango
        [1] => Melancia
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta criar o array novamente:

```
$newArray = array_values($oldArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não necessariamente precisa criar outra variável, pode utilizar a mesma e sobrepor os valores:

```
$matriz = array_values($matriz);
```

Caso sempre vá tirar somente o primeiro valor da array, é comumente utilizado o `array_shift()`, já que ele reordena automaticamente o array:

```
array_shift($matriz);
```

Comment: Legal, nunca usei o `array_shift`, sobre criar uma nova, exato,  não precisa mesmo, por isso disse apenas **criar o array novamente**, podendo ser com o mesmo nome ou não.